Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex..ctor
Upgrade to 10.3.1
Full error:
Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex..ctor(Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.Factories.IProviderContextFactory, System.String)'.

Any clue what/where to look?
EDIT:
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex..ctor(Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.Factories.IProviderContextFactory, System.String)'.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex..ctor(String name, String connectionStringName, String totalParallelServices, IIndexPropertyStore propertyStore, String group, ServiceCollectionClient serviceCollectionClient, ICloudSearchProviderIndexName cloudSearchProviderIndexName, AbstractCloudSearchContextFactory contextFactory) +0
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex..ctor(String name, String connectionStringName, String totalParallelServices, IIndexPropertyStore propertyStore, String group, ServiceCollectionClient serviceCollectionClient) +168
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex..ctor(String name, String connectionStringName, String totalParallelServices, IIndexPropertyStore propertyStore) +92

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +313
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +128
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +842
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +309
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +732
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.get_CsConfig() +16
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.GeAllIndexes() +11
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp..ctor(BaseSearchIndexes indexes) +59
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs args) +72
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +918
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719


Can you please share the full stack trace?

updated above :)

I have added the answer below. Let me know in case you face any issues.

You are getting this error since starting from Sitecore XP 10.2, it is no longer possible to use the Azure Search provider. Details on the Azure Search compatibility can be found here.
You will need to switch to Solr search to resolve this issue. In order to configure Solr Search in the website, below settings needs to be configured.

Inside the App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config file of the website, you will need to provide Solr url.

<add name="solr.search" connectionString="https://localhost:8983/solr">


Change the search provider to Solr inside the Web.config file.

<add key="search:define" value="Solr" />

This will configure your solution to use Solr Search provider. More details on the Solr configuration can be found here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Hello ckhanna, both are already updated, but still same error is encountered

@bonhaku Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex should only run when search:define configuration is set to Azure. Can you check inside sitecore\admin\showconfig.aspx page is CloudSearchProviderIndex still showing.

unfortunately i am not able to load showconfig because it is also server error. is there another way to check this?

@bonhaku can we can connect over Sitecore Slack?

@bonhaku Can you also make sure you disable all the config files where Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex is referred?

We had a separate effort for the azure removal. Already merged that and fixed the issue.

But currently having this error.
Method 'GetAsync' in type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Availability.Retryer.SolrConnectionWithRetry' from assembly 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Im sorry my application to join sitecore slack hasn't been approved yet. :(

@bonhaku This seems to a different issue..You can accept the answer for the question raised as it is fixed.

You can raise a separate question for this issue including the stack trace. Hope that works!!!

I got the incorrect index names on this. Solved now. thankyou ckhanna :)

@bonhaku Glad to hear that. Please make sure to accept this answer in order to help other members in the community.
